# GWT requestfactory: can not get a list of valueproxy inside an EntityProxy

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, objectify

```
class MyEntityProxy
{
    @Load
    MyEntityProxy2 ep;

}
public class MyEntityProxy2
{
    @Embed
    List<MyValueProxy> values;

}
class MyValueProxy
{
    String name;
    String value;
}
```

At client side, i hope to send a request to get a list of `MyEntityProxy`, with `MyEntityProxy2` and its value list returned.
 From debug i can see at server side all `MyValueProxy` list has been retrieved and returned. but at client side, there are no
 valueProxy there. eg.getMyValueProxies()==null

I append path info when requesting `MyEntityProxy` list, like this:

```
String[] paths=new String[]{"ep","ep.values"};
```

If i send a request to get `MyEntityProxy2` list directly with paths("`values`") and all values can be returned successfully.

Any ideas about this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work. Can you check with Chrome's Developer Tools/Firebug and check the content of the HTTP request?

Comment: Hi Umit, your reminding is quite helpful, i'm checking on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ümit is right, the above code works, other logic mistake lead to this problem, thanks Umit for his great reminding.